# Bootstrap icon wrong positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm new to CSS and HTML, so I got stuck on a very stupid step. The thing is that fa-list-ul icon is wrong positioned. Without `text-align:center` it positions fine. Any way to fix it? Thanks for spending your time with my problem.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqkvv8es/)

And here is my code :

```
.player{padding:.75rem 1rem;margin-bottom:1rem;line-height:36px}
.player_play{font-size:36px;vertical-align:middle}
.radio_name{vertical-align:middle}
.radio_icon{padding-right:5px;vertical-align:middle}
.radio_select{font-size:20px;vertical-align:middle}
```

```
<nav class="player">
<div class="container">
<div class="float-left">
<i class="fa fa-play-circle player_play action"></i>
</div>
<div class="radio_volume">
<i class="fa fa-volume-down"></i>
<i class="fa fa-music radio_icon accent_color"></i><span class="radio_name">&nbsp;Anison</span>
</div>
<div class="float-right">
<i class="fa fa-list-ul radio_select action"></i>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Which icon on what position do you want it exactly?

Comment: @RonnieOosting sorry, fa fa-list-ul is at the bottom(see JSFiddle)

Comment: Do you want to have the fa fa-list-ul on the bottom?

Comment: @RonnieOosting sorry, silly me, my English is bad, I mean that the fa fa-list-ul is not on the same line as other icons

Comment: Do you use bootstrap v3?

Comment: @RonnieOosting v4 latest beta

Comment: Can you try this? https://jsfiddle.net/8kkdhpw3/ its a dirty solution, but perhaps this helps you in the right direction

Comment: @RonnieOosting the problem is still here ;( Anyway, thanks for help
https://jsfiddle.net/fqkvv8es/1/

Comment: It's because of the div. Let me solve yours quick, sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Bootstrap's classes, which results in less code than what the chosen answer uses:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqkvv8es/5/)

**HTML**

```
<nav class="player">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <i class="fa fa-play-circle player_play action"></i>
      <div class="radio_volume">
        <i class="fa fa-volume-down"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-music radio_icon accent_color"></i><span class="radio_name">&nbsp;Station</span>
      </div>
      <i class="fa fa-list-ul radio_select action"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.player {
  padding: .75rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  line-height: 36px
}

.player_play {
  font-size: 36px;
}

.radio_icon {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.radio_select {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqkvv8es/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Using `display: flex` will make every element inside that container have the same horizontal size so this should solve your problem:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.float-left {
  flex: 1;
}
.radio_volume {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}
.float-right {
  flex: 1;
}
.float-right i {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

also here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fqkvv8es/3/